# Nginx Location Directive - match folder but not subfolders

Tags: nginx, location, config

What I'm looking for is an nginx location block to match a particular folder, but NOT match its subfolders. I'm guessing this would require a regular expression match??? (BTW, I've googled several possibilities and can't figure this one out.)

For example, I want to add a custom HTTP header to URLs in folder `/classes/`, but I don't want to add this header for files in these folders: `/classes/100/`, `/classes/101/`, `/classes/beginner/`, etc.

It would be too cumbersome to require all subfolders to have their own location blocks. Is something like this possible?